# Difference between "force stop" and leaving the phone for a few hours

Tags: android

I've had a couple of game apps on the market which attempt to save the users progress through the game with some code like this (simplified):

```
public class Globals extends Application
{
    public void onCreate()
    {
         settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", 0);
    }

    public void get_state()
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            game_progress = settings.getInt("progress", 1);
        }
    }

    public void save_state()
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

            editor.putInt("progress",game_progress);

            editor.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

This appears to work fine 99% of the time but every now and then I have had reports from users that their progress was lost, but nobody has ever been able to give me a sequence of actions which will enable me to repeat the bug... until now. The steps involve pressing the "home" button to exit the program and then waiting several hours. Then when they run the game again, their progress is lost. Frustratingly this sequence can not be shortened, doing a "force stop" instead of leaving the phone for several hours does not have the same effect.

Presumably if the phone is left for a few hours, some or all of the activities within the application may get shut down in a way which is subtly different from a force stop... but I have no idea how.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I should explain how these functions are called from the various activities that comprise my games. Here's an example, but I call gs.save_state() from several other places too, just for good measure.

```
    public class Main_GamePlay extends Activity
    {
        Globals gs;
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
             gs = ((Globals) getApplicationContext());
        }
        protected void onPause()
        {
            gs.save_state();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is "this"? When do you call get/save_state functions? You should save state in onPause method of your activity.

Comment: I've edited the original post so you can now see that the "this" is in fact "Globals.this". BTW, I do indeed call save_state from the onPause of my game's main activity.

Comment: Can you not use Application object for synchronization? Android can use application object to sync own stuff. Create a separate lock and retest your app. Why do you need synchronized at all?

Comment: The graphics and the physics parts of my game run on separate threads... but I am no expert on multithreading at all. I just hacked someone else's threading code without properly understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

may be there should not be any proper sequence as what is happening in your case is memory reclaiming .When you press home you app will go to background state which has higher priority to be reclaim by the Garbage Collector.So you should try saving your current state by other means than shared preferences.May be you should save state on press of home of your current activity if it is possible.

Hope this give you brief idea about what you want.